# 100% height block with vertical text

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, vertical-text

I have a block of a variable height in which I want to put another block with 100% height and vertical text (bottom-to-top direction) and stack it to the left side of the outer block. Is there a way to achieve it with CSS transforms but without width and height calculations in JS?

[image: Sketch]

This is what I could get so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.block1 {
    border: 4px solid #888;
    height: 120px;
    width: 200px;
}
.block2 {
    height: 100%;
    border: 4px solid red;
}
.msg {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14pt;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: center center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block1">
        <table class="block2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="msg">Hi there!</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: My test]

You can see that the inner block's computed width is the same as the text width before rotation.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the picture of what I want to get in the end:

[image]

It's a horizontal stripe with items stacked to its left side, and with a vertical header block. Stripe's height is variable, so items should adapt and the header's text should remain centered.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I believe you were only using a `<table>` because it seemed to be the easiest way to achieve what you were looking for, so I cut it out of the equation and used semantic HTML instead. If there was another reason, I apologize in advance and you should be able to port the styles over to use a `<table>` instead.

See the [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hKp7f/4/) to view the code in action. Or, continue on to the code:

### HTML

```
<section class="wrapper">
    <header><h1>Test</h1></header>
    <article>Text.</article><!--
    --><article>More text.</article><!--
    --><article>Photos of cats.</article><!--
    --><article>More photos of cats.</article>
</section>
```

### CSS

```css
.wrapper {
    margin:1em;
    position:relative;
    padding-left:2em; /* line-height of .wrapper div:first-child span */
    background:#fed;
}
.wrapper header {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:2em; /* line-height of .wrapper div:first-child span */
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
.wrapper header h1 {
    -moz-transform-origin:0 50%;
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 50%;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    -o-transform-origin:0 50%;
    -o-transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    -ms-transform-origin:0 50%;
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    transform-origin:0 50%;
    transform:rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    height:2em; /* line-height of .wrapper div:first-child span */
    margin:auto;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1em;
    line-height:2em; /* Copy to other locations */
}
.wrapper article {
    display:inline-block;
    width:25%;
    padding:1em 1em 1em 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

### How it works

The `<header>` is set to the height of `.wrapper` and has it's `width` set to `2em` (value of `line-height` for the `<h1>`). Then, the `<h1>` is vertically aligned (with `top:0;bottom:0;height:2em;margin:auto;` [`2em` is also from `line-height`]). Once the `<h1>` is vertically aligned, it is rotated counter-clockwise 90 degrees by the middle of its left side. In order to make the `<h1>` visible again, it is translated `50%` vertically (to pull it back onto the screen horizontally) and `-50%` horizontally (to vertically align it). And yes, the wording is correct--everything just gets confusing once you rotate by [-]90 degrees ;)

### Gotchas

- Only a static "height" is supported for the `<h1>`. In this case, only 1 line is supported.
- Wrapping will not work (I've actually disabled it in this example), so anything that doesn't fit in the `height` of `.wrapper` will be hidden.

Comment: Took one look at this problem, and immediately thought of this kind of solution. Great answer! Curiosity though, using the code you've provided, how might you go about "right-aligning" (or top-aligning, I suppose) the text that's been rotated?

Comment: Turns out just removing `margin: auto;` will do the trick, and to change the positioning vertically, you can just adjust the `margin-top/bottom` properties.

Comment: @spatar, is this answer missing something for the bounty? Or just waiting until the end to assign it?

Comment: @Nightfirecat, actually, it would be better to: remove `bottom:0;` and `margin:auto;`, change `transform-origin` to `0 0`, and change `transform` to `rotate(-90deg) translate(-100%, 0)` for `.wrapper header h1`. See [top-aligned example](http://jsfiddle.net/hKp7f/2/). To align it to the bottom, do the same thing, except remove `top:0;` instead of `bottom:0;`. See the [bottom-aligned example](http://jsfiddle.net/hKp7f/3/).

Comment: @bfrohs, the answer is absolutely worth bounty but when I try to give it to you I see a message: "You may award your bounty in 27 minutes" (yesterday it was 11 hours)

Comment: Didn't think of using transform-origin. Nice, bfrohs!

Comment: Works great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the transform styles more thoroughly, it doesn't appear so. You would need to know the precise height of the outter `div`.

Comment: Most likely you are right. But I will wait couple more days. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. If someone else _does_ post a solution, I'll be very eager to read it!

Answer (score 0):

The best I could come up with is this: http://jsfiddle.net/EwgtT/

The variable height of block1 won't be a problem, but the variable height of your message is; it will always start at the bottom.

**Edit:**
Updated, so it works well in FF and IE: http://jsfiddle.net/EwgtT/2/

Comment: I tried your code in Firefox and the text appears at the bottom of the page, out of the red block.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.block2 {
    width: 100%;
    border: 4px solid red;
}
.msg {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 14pt;
}
.block1 {
    border: 4px solid #888;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: right top;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right top;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="block1">
        <table class="block2">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="msg">Hi there!</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
<style>
.block1{
width:500px;
margin-left:-500px;
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

- switched the transformation to the outer element,
- then used width attribute to define the height at the bottom of the page (when you play with that, you are actually playing with the height there.)
- and for the empty left space visible after rotation, I used the variable width (height) as negative margin.

You can see it here: http://pastehtml.com/view/c0hl7zxci.html

Comment: Actually I don't want to rotate the outer `div` because the idea was to stack more `divs` inside with regular (not rotated) text. Sorry if I wasn't clear. I'm attaching a new picture to the question to display what is my final goal.