# rotating text on a table using css3

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table for printing purpose.
As seen in many forms, I want vertically rotated text and both left and right side of the form.

So far I have achieved this

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/P8AZD/

This has two problems

1. I wanted the border td widths as 50 px with the text spanning more area. Currently the rotated text also gets clipped to 50px. How to overcome this?
2. The style `rotate-right` has incorrect `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix`. It has been copied from `.rotate-left`. What does the values (M11, M12, M21, M22) in the filter denote?

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843380/100-height-block-with-vertical-text) is a very usefull post for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/P8AZD/7/

I added a div around your text and made it not wrap