# CSS3 transform rotate text, fixed position left and right, vertically centered

Tags: css, position, transform, vertical-alignment, css-transforms

I'm trying to position one element to the left and one to the right of the browser window, both contains an `ul` with CSS transform rotate. I have managed to position `.rotate-left` and its `ul` to the left, but I have been unable to position the `ul` inside `.rotate-right` to the right. (It needs to be visible on a horizontal line from right to left if transform is not supported.)

CSS:

```
.rotate-left ul li,
.rotate-right ul li {
    display: inline;
}

.rotate-left {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 10em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: silver;
}

.rotate-left ul {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: auto;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.rotate-right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 10em; 
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: silver;
}

.rotate-right ul {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 1.5em; 
    margin: auto;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
       -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="rotate-left">
    <ul>
        <li>left</li>
        <li>left</li>
        <li>left</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="rotate-right">
    <ul>
        <li>right</li>
        <li>right</li>
        <li>right</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

-

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FtyEG

I have built upon this [100% height block with vertical text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843380/100-height-block-with-vertical-text).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I solved it and cleaned the code up a bit.

```
.left,
.right {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: auto;
}

.left {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 0 50%;
         -o-transform-origin: 0 50%;
            transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
       -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
        -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
         -o-transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
            transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-50%, 50%);
}

.right {
    right: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
       -moz-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
         -o-transform-origin: 100% 50%;
            transform-origin: 100% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%, 50%);
       -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%, 50%);
        -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%, 50%);
         -o-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%, 50%);
            transform: rotate(90deg) translate(50%, 50%);
}
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LHeaB

Comment: This is an outstanding solution, thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I think that I get it more or less right. It would be:

```
.rotate-right ul {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 78% 100%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translate(0%, 0%);
```

You don't need to translate if you choose ok the transform origin; going to 78% would be to compensate for the li width

Comment: I just noted that I forgot to add `padding: 0;` on `ul`, sorry. I have updated the demo. Your solution is still close tho. About 30px of vertically.