# PHP Image(png) positioning and rotate

Tags: php, css

I have an image (arrow.png), I would like to positioning it from left/right/top etc. and how do I rotate the image by a variable what has value from 0-360?

**My PHP code**

```
 <?php $degrees = 270;

    echo "<img src='arrow.png'>", "<div id='windfr'>";
    $rotate = imagerotate($degrees, 0); ?>
```

**My CSS:**

```
<style>
  .windfr {
    z-index: 8;
    display: block;
    position:relative;
    left: 425px;
    top: 670px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: If you really want to use PHP GD2 to manipulate the image, your `<img>` has to call the PHP script that will generate this image. Keep in mind however that image processing is CPU intensive, this is not something you want to do in your web server.

Comment: @Havenard - of course you want to do image manipulation on the server, but not on each request. The result should be saved somewhere

Comment: @Philipp Well yeah, I meant, unless it's absolutely necessary. A simple rotation can be achieved with CSS or SVG, in fact there are lots of editing that can be done with SVG. Leave image processing to the client side whenever it is possible. Ideally the server should be processing trust sensitive operations only to optimize it's limited resources and responsiveness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$degrees = 270;

echo "<img src='Asset 1.png' style='transform: rotate(".$degrees."deg);'>", "<div id='windfr'>";

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, the rotation is working but my code for positioning isnt. Maybe do you know what is wrong?

Comment: you can use `transform-origin` css property for positioning [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15306032/css3-transform-rotate-text-fixed-position-left-and-right-vertically-centered) @Bence

Comment: Yes I tried and it works fine! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do that with CSS only:

```
img{
    -ms-transform: rotate(20deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

Obviously you can to change the degree of the rotation as you desire.

More info here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

Good luck!