# How can I control the width of a <div> with display:table; with a <p> element inside with display:table-cell

Tags: html, css

I have a layout, where I have to make a vertical centeret, with a rotated text inside.
See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C7mCc/3/
I use `display:table;` and `display:table-cell;` to make the vertical centering, which is working good. 
The HTML

```
<div id="top-banner-advertising-text" class="v-center">
 <p class="v-c-content">Annonce</p>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
.v-center {
    display: table;
}

.v-center .v-c-content {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But I only want the `#top-banner-advertising-text` to have a width of 15px. Like in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C7mCc/4/ where I have removed the `.v-center` and `.v-c-content` and therefore do not have the text vertical centered.

How can I control the width of the div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up being a lot more complicated than I expected. To control the width you must take into consideration your parent divs. There is an excellent explanation of this here:

[100% height block with vertical text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843380/100-height-block-with-vertical-text)

Although this in order to help you out I went ahead and figured out how to switch this code up  to swap the text to the other side of the img for you.

my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/C7mCc/6/

To answer your questions, "How do I control the width".

This is done by taking the following lines in the css and making sure they match,

```
   padding-left:2em; /* line-height of .wrapper div:first-child span */

   width:2em; /* line-height of .wrapper div:first-child span */

   height:2em; /* line-height of .wrapper div:first-child span */

   line-height:2em; /* Copy to other locations */
```

Remember since your vertical now you must think about the padding left.
basically your line height padding left width and height come in to play.

We control them with em in order to make sure they are sized correctly.

Let me know if you need anymore help.

Comment: Thank you. This post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843380/100-height-block-with-vertical-text helped me very much. You can see my working fiddle now: http://jsfiddle.net/C7mCc/7/

Comment: Awesome. Ya that post was really well put together. I'm glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the not selector:

```
/* if it must not have the vertical centering class */
#top-banner-advertising-text:not(.v-center) {
    width: 15px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C7mCc/5/

Alternately, you could leave the width as you have it in your 2nd example and add this:

```
#top-banner-advertising-text.v-center {
    width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to set a width for an element displayed as table, you use : `table-layout:fixed;`

But you do not say that you want as well to rotate a text.

To rotate that text, you will need `white-space:nowrap` if more than  one word (15px is really small).

to replace that text in middle, you will need `translate();` and set that text in a container displayed as a table, so it expands over 15px and makes translate usable.

here an example with 2 version rotated 90 and -90 degres : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JuAio.

For older IE, search for the old `writing-mode` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ;) .